# { symbol not accepting in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

The `{` symbol is not working in eclipse.
If I try to use it, it turns on and off the ***Skip All Breakpoints*** opportunity.

But its shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +<kbd>Alt</kbd>  +  <kbd>B</kbd> .
So for  some reason when I press  <kbd>AltGr</kbd>  +  <kbd>B</kbd>  it thinks I pressed   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>Alt</kbd>  +  <kbd>B</kbd> .

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: I assume that you have checked that it works in the notepad editor, right?

Comment: Yes it works in all IDE exept for Eclipse :(

Comment: FYI AltrGr == Alt + Ctrl [wiki ftw](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltGr_key)

Comment: Interesting... It says, that in some original US PC keyboards AltGr is equal to Alt+Ctrl, but I am form Hungary. In this case, how can I change this shortcut in eclipse?

Comment: maybe you just "switched keyboard" (shift + alt) ..to different language/region ...(in eclipse window only...since you could type it here:)

Comment: I highly recommend you use English keyboard layout in an IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Ok it looks like I solved this, I just simply changed the ***Skip All Breakpoints*** shortcut in General Setting for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> and now works everything fine. Thank you for your helps!! :D